# Collectionview custom cell layout/behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working with a collectionview, that are sliding horizontally, and trying to do a custom layout of the cells, similar to the iphone "app closer". I have no idea how to achieve an effect like this, or where to start, so I was hoping to get some pointers.
I'm very bad at explaining myself, so I've tried illustrating the desired effect, from how it behaves now, till how it should behave.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think you should see the example shown here https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel, Here you will find many types of effects, Then you will get atleast idea how to start and what to do

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks like the exactly right engine for a custom effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Worked with a similar view like this.This is the github [link](https://github.com/Rokimkar/CardLayout) of my project.
[image: This is the screenshot of the view]
The only difference between your requirement and my view is you need to zoom the left cell too. To achieve this view I encountered two major problem:

1) Stopping the scroll exactly when the two cell(left cell and right cell) are equally exposed, for that I have included the following code in my CollectionView.m file.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    float pageWidth = 240; // width + space

    float currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    float targetOffset = targetContentOffset->x;
    float newTargetOffset = 0;

    if (targetOffset > currentOffset)
        newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
    else
        newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;

    if (newTargetOffset < 0)
        newTargetOffset = 0;
    else if (newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width)
        newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width;

    targetContentOffset->x = currentOffset;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];

    int index = newTargetOffset / pageWidth;

    if (index == 0) { // If first index
        CollectionViewCell *cell =(CollectionViewCell *) [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index  inSection:0]];
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[self cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index + 1  inSection:0]];
        //cell.transform = TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE;

    }else{
        CollectionViewCell *cell =(CollectionViewCell *)[self cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]];
        //cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        index --; // left
        cell =(CollectionViewCell *)[self cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]];
          //  cell.transform = TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE;
        index ++;
        index ++; // right
        cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[self cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]];
        //cell.transform = TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE;
    }
}
```

2) Secondly you need to provide proper constraint to the cell to achieve the requirement, for that I have used **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** class.
In this I provide proper constraint to the visible cells. FlowLayout code looks like below:

```
#import "CollectionLayout.h"


@implementation CollectionLayout
{
    NSIndexPath *mainIndexPath;
}

-(void)prepareLayout{
    [super prepareLayout];
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] copy];
    CATransform3D theTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    const CGFloat theScale = 1.05f;
    theTransform = CATransform3DScale(theTransform, theScale, theScale, 1.0f);
    attributes.transform3D=theTransform;
    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    NSArray *attributesSuper = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSArray *attributes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:attributesSuper copyItems:YES];
    NSArray *cellIndices = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSIndexPath *neededIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    for(NSInteger i=0;i<cellIndices.count;i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cellIndices objectAtIndex:i];
        if(indexPath.row>neededIndexPath.row){
            neededIndexPath=indexPath;
        }
        NSLog(@"%ld,%ld",(long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section);
    }
    if(cellIndices.count==0){
        mainIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }else{
        if(neededIndexPath.row>0)
            mainIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:neededIndexPath.row-1 inSection:0];
    }

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes)
    {
        [self applyTransformToLayoutAttributes:attribute];
    }
    return attributes;
}

-(void) applyTransformToLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attribute{
    if(attribute.indexPath.row == mainIndexPath.row){
        attribute.size = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width-40, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
        attribute.zIndex+=10;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Transform related

@end
```

Once you clone the project from my github link, you will understand easily what I have done and you can write your own code to achieve your view.You will only need to provide your constraint in this part of the code. **You also need to adjust the zIndex properly for each cell**.

```
 -(void) applyTransformToLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attribute{
        if(attribute.indexPath.row == mainIndexPath.row){
            attribute.size = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width-40, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
            attribute.zIndex+=10;
        }
    }
```

I hope you got my point.

***note: I have tested the github code only on iPhone 5s, you might need to tweak a little bit for other devices.***

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a great inspiration, and I managed to do my own variant of it, that worked exactly like expected. That's great work!